# Simple numberDisplay from reduceCount with dc.js

Tags: dc.js

I'm starting with dc and I'm turning around for several days about a simple thing I can't do. I've got a classical data sample of payments with this structure:
{date: "2011-11-14T16:17:54Z", quantity: 2, total: 190, tip: 100, type: "tab"}
I just want to display the number of different kind of types of payments. There are 3. I can display it in the console, but not in the the chart. I have tried lot of different things but none is working. I have something working with reduceSum, but not with reduceCount, the structure of the object seems to be different.
Thanks for your help

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1"/>
    <title>Crossfilter</title>
    <script src="crossfilter.js"></script>
    <script src="d3.js"></script>
    <script src="dc.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
My count :    
<div id="category-count"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var payments = crossfilter([
  {date: "2011-11-14T16:17:54Z", quantity: 2, total: 190, tip: 100, type: "tab"},
  {date: "2011-11-14T16:20:19Z", quantity: 2, total: 190, tip: 100, type: "tab"},
  {date: "2011-11-14T16:28:54Z", quantity: 1, total: 300, tip: 200, type: "visa"},
  {date: "2011-11-14T16:30:43Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
  {date: "2011-11-14T16:48:46Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
  {date: "2011-11-14T16:53:41Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
  {date: "2011-11-14T16:54:06Z", quantity: 1, total: 100, tip: 0, type: "cash"},
  {date: "2011-11-14T16:58:03Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
  {date: "2011-11-14T17:07:21Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
  {date: "2011-11-14T17:22:59Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
  {date: "2011-11-14T17:25:45Z", quantity: 2, total: 200, tip: 0, type: "cash"},
  {date: "2011-11-14T17:29:52Z", quantity: 1, total: 200, tip: 100, type: "visa"}
]);

var paymentsByType = payments.dimension(function(d) { return d.type; });
var countType = paymentsByType.group().reduceCount();
console.log(countType.size());

dc.numberDisplay('#category-count')
  .formatNumber(d3.format("d"))
  .group(countType)
  .valueAccessor( function (d) { return d.size(); } );

</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally the `numberDisplay` is expecting to show the result of an aggregation - so it will call [`groupAll.value()`](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#crossfilter_groupAll) if it's given a `groupAll` object. Or if it's given an ordinary group it will call [`group.all()`](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#group_all) and then choose the top one according to the [`chart.ordering()`](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#ordering__anchor) function.

Displaying the number of bins is a slightly different problem, and I suspect this is where you're running into trouble. (I can't explain why something would work for `reduceSum` but not `reduceCount`, as those should produce the same shape of result.)

I'd suggest using a "fake groupAll", like this:

```
function bin_counter(group) {
  return {
    value: function() {
      return group.all().length;
    }
  };
}
```

Apply it to the group before passing it to the widget, and then use an identity accessor, since the default accessor is not helpful here:

```
dc.numberDisplay( /* ... */ )
  // ...
  .group(bin_counter(countType))
  .valueAccessor(x => x); // or function(x) { return x; } in ES5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon. It does work this way. That is not the most intuitive but it makes the job. By the way, thanks too for the scala-like synthax x => x instead of the verbose java-like type. I really love it.